# how to display Value On select change in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div { color:red; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
            <option>Chocolate</option>
            <option selected="selected">Candy</option>    
            <option>Taffy</option>
            <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
            <option>Fudge</option>
            <option>Cookie</option>    
        </select>
        <div></div>
        <script>
            $("select").change(function() {
                var str = "";
                $("select option:selected").each(function() {
                    str += $(this).text() + " ";
                });
                $("div").text(str);
            }).change();
        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

This my code I want to display on console in jsp on Select change passing the value.I want to Print onslected item in Jsp page

```
<%  
    String k=request.getParameter("sweets");
    out.println(k);
%>
```

Like this I want to Print on select item data please help me

Comment: Could you please clarify more? Where do you want to put the jsp values?

Comment: Actully i need to pass the valu in on on slect change value insted of Button clcik http://182.18.132.100:8088/cbdtforprsite/circularnotication.aspx?tabid=tab_CIR  see in this in Year slection the value is changes i want actully this

Comment: please tell me am stucking in this

Answer (score 0):

Enclose select box with-in form tag and in 
onchange method of select , trigger form submit

```
<form id="resultform" action="resultPage.jsp">
       <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
            <option>Chocolate</option>
            <option selected="selected">Candy</option>    
            <option>Taffy</option>
            <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
            <option>Fudge</option>
            <option>Cookie</option>    
        </select>
</form>
```

In jquery method write

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $('#resultform').submit();
}
```

Comment: can u please tell when we have to Enclose form please tell me that is my code please

Comment: OK But i need to Get in the same jsppage and Once user will slect ths it display value in same Jsp page i have write my code in Index.jsp file

Comment: http://182.18.132.100:8088/cbdtforprsite/circularnotication.aspx?tabid=tab_CIR  see this and select Year i have to display listdata on itemslect Year

Comment: You need concepts like Ajax for doing this.

Comment: please help how i will do this am doing first time i have tried much so i m unable to do this.

Comment: for this i will highly obliged to you

Comment: learn basics of AJAX, AJAX basic simple example will work for you..check http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ in jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: if that is the case, how will you pay? try to learn by yourself and apply it. if u struck in that ask about that.(dot)